# How does the TPS based rate limiting work?

Tags: wso2, throttling

What is the logic used in WSO2 API manager for TPS based rate limiting? Does it aggregate request count for 1 second or calculate the rate based on instant?

I have been working in WSO2 API manager and applied 75TPS for an API. It got throttled at 45TPS. Received TPS was calculated using gateway logs.